# Expression matches but Python still returns wrong output

Tags: python, python-requests

I am checking a string against a selector. The selector does match the string but `Python` still returns `False`, why?

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector

url = 'https://www.pickles.com.au/cars/item/-/details/CP-09-16--Built-06-16--Holden--Colorado--RG-MY16-LS-Crew-Cab--Cab-Chassis-Dual-Cab--5-Seats--4-Doors/302151687'

r = requests.get(url)
rsp = Selector(text=r.text)

current_status = rsp.xpath('//h6[@class="mt-2"]/text()[2]').get()
print(current_status)
print('This item has been sold.' == current_status)
```

**Output:**

```
This item has been sold. 
False
```

Comment: Print the `repr()` of the string, so you can see *exactly* what it contains - could be a non-printable character, could be a trailing space, etc.

Comment: What does `repr(current_status)` output? The two strings are clearly, but perhaps not *obviously*, different.

Comment: Yes, it fine now.

Comment: There was a space as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra space at the end of the `current_status`. Use the `rstrip` to remove it on condition.

It can be observed in the below code that I could recreate and resolve:

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector
url = 'https://www.pickles.com.au/cars/item/-/details/CP-09-16--Built-06-16--Holden--Colorado--RG-MY16-LS-Crew-Cab--Cab-Chassis-Dual-Cab--5-Seats--4-Doors/302151687'

r = requests.get(url)
rsp = Selector(text=r.text)

current_status = rsp.xpath('//h6[@class="mt-2"]/text()[2]').get()
print(current_status)
print('This item has been sold.' == current_status.rstrip())
```